# Java Script not working on my website

Tags: javascript

The following script is not working when i upload it to my webpage. It works fine and loads the url if I try it on 'TryIt Editor' in w3school.com. I have changed the domain name in this example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var x=1;
        function changeLink()
        {
           x=x+1;
           var y="http://example.com/basicone/image"+x+".html";
           document.getElementById('iframe-a').src=y;
        }
    </script>

    <iframe id="iframe-a" seamless src="http://example.com/basicone/image1.html" height="450" width="1000" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    <button id="button" onclick="changeLink()">Next</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what error do you get? does console say anything?

Comment: no error, nothing happens when i click the button

Comment: You need to add `type="button"` to the button, otherwise it will act as a `submit` in certain browsers

Comment: That's only in a form

Comment: try to move script into <head> tag

Comment: do you have these pages on your server `http://example.com/basicone/image"+x+".html`?

Comment: see here -> http://jsfiddle.net/y9NuG/1/, it's working

Comment: I moved the script into <head> and now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it doesn't works? It's really strange, especially because js it's clientside

try to change alert the url, after it has been changed, with this code:

```
<script>
var x=1;
function changeLink()
{

x=x+1;
var y="http://example.com/basicone/image"+x+".html";

document.getElementById('iframe-a').src=y;
alert(document.getElementById('iframe-a').src);
}
</script>

<iframe id="iframe-a" seamless src="http://example.com/basicone/image1.html" height="450" width="1000" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<button id="button" onclick="changeLink()">Next</button>
```

Comment: The alert box does not pop

Comment: @TanveerDewan I forgotten the button,have you added it? <button id="button" onclick="changeLink()">Next</button>

Comment: I am adding this as code to a page on my wordpress site. does not work there. Works fine if i save this as .html on my local computer and then execute it.

Comment: @TanveerDewan because it works for me, can you give us the page of your site, where the script is?

Comment: @TanveerDewan it must works if you dind't change browser and it works in the other pages

Comment: I added the script to <head> section and it works now. By any chance you might know Why it does not work in the <body>. I am using wordpress.

Comment: @TanveerDewan take a look at this post: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51140

Comment: you said you added it as "as code to a page on my wordpress site". If you mean you edited the page in the admin with the wordpress editor, then the editor probably strips <script> tags